# Logical error in binary and integer addition

Tags: python

While writing a program, I stumbled upon an error on my code which was preventing the desired output.

```
n = 10
median = ((n>>1) + (n>>1 + 1)) >> 1
```

The output of the program was `3`

When changing the code to :

```
n = 10
median = ((n>>1) + (int(n>>1) + 1)) >> 1
```

The output was `5`.

What is the logical error here?

Comment: You don't need the `int`, just the parentheses - `+` is higher precedence than `>>`, your first version was effectively `((n>>1) + (n>>2)) >> 1`

Comment: So `(n >> 1 + 1)` is executed like `((n + 1) >> 1)` ?

Comment: No, it's not going to swap the order of the operands, it's executed like `n >> (1 + 1)`, or just `n >> 2`.

Comment: Looks like I need to revisit operators and precedence.